# How call Orleans grain method without reference of grain implementation?

Tags: .net, .net-core, orleans

How call Orleans grain method without reference of grain implementation?

- Grain client - .Net Core application.
- Grain implementation class - classic .Net Framework library, and cannot be added to .Net Core application.

Comment: Adding the grain interfaces to a Core project, referencing it from the Framework implementation and the Core client doesn't work?

Comment: @lmagyar Don't work with error:  Cannot find an implementation class for grain interface: IBlaBla. Make sure the grain assembly was correctly deployed and loaded in the silo.
And documentation writed: add interface and implementation references to client code.

Comment: Maybe you missed something, eg. referencing the Grain base class from the implementation, this can cause errors like this, because yes, there is no implementation for the interface (an implementation inherits the interface AND the base Grain class). See my answer below.

Comment: @Thanks for project sample. I miss reference to Microsoft.Orleans.OrleansCodeGenerator.Build

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the client project reference only the interface project (Core -> Standard).

From the host project reference the implementation project (Full -> Full) and the implementation project references the interface project (Full -> Standard).

It works like a charm, see: https://github.com/lmagyar/SO_Question_50689964

Answer (score 0):

## Minimal Orleans sample

### Server

.Net Framework Console App

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Orleans.Core.Abstractions
Install-Package Microsoft.Orleans.OrleansCodeGenerator.Build
Install-Package Microsoft.Orleans.Server

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await StartSilo();
    }
    static async Task StartSilo()
    {
        using (var host = new SiloHostBuilder()
            .UseLocalhostClustering()
            //.ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.AddConsole())
            .ConfigureApplicationParts(parts => parts.AddApplicationPart(typeof(SampleGrain).Assembly).WithReferences())
            .Build())
        {
            await host.StartAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Silo started. Press any key to terminate...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }


}

public class SampleGrain : Grain, ISample
{
    public Task<string> Ping(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Pinged with '{message}'");
        return Task.FromResult($"Message '{message}' received");
    }
}
```

### Interfaces

.Net Standard class library

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Orleans.Core.Abstractions

public interface ISample : IGrainWithStringKey
{
    Task<string> Ping(string message);
}
```

### Client

.Net Core Console App

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Orleans.OrleansCodeGenerator.Build
Install-Package Microsoft.Orleans.Client

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await PingSample();
}

static async Task PingSample()
{
    using (var client = new ClientBuilder()
        .UseLocalhostClustering()
        //.ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.AddConsole())
        .ConfigureApplicationParts(parts => parts.AddApplicationPart(typeof(ISample).Assembly).WithReferences())
        .Build())
    {
        await client.Connect();
        Console.WriteLine("Client successfully connected to silo host.");

        var sample = client.GetGrain<ISample>("one");

        var result = await sample.Ping("hello");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

}
```

https://github.com/Serj-Tm/Orleans.MinimalSample